# "Recover" broken games on Xbox?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, fifa-12

My Xbox 360 lagged, i gave it a little slap which brought the disc out. Now the game, which happens to be fifa 12 is scratched and unplayable. I tried repairing it but failed and made things worse for myself.

Is there a way i can download it from the xbox marketplace without paying again? I can prove that i indeed have the disc, the box etc. even an ultimate team. What am i to do now?

I don't really want to contact EA because their forums require regestration into their stupid system, it's called Origin or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could borrow a disc from a friend to install the game to your hard drive.  Then use your disc to run FIFA.

My friend and I did the with MW2 - he severely scratched his disc, so I brought mine over his house to install the game.  It worked fine afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to do this.

If the fault had been with the disc, you might have had a warranty depending on when you bought it; but as it was your own action then you must face the consequences.

Comment: Why was this downvoted ? Either you bought insurance on the game or you didn't. If you didn't, you have to bite the bullet and buy a new game.  ~$60 lesson learned ?

Comment: agreed - upvoted. Slapping your console is not exactly a recommended course of action.